# Monitor where request come from

Tags: monitoring, request

I'm looking to monitor where the people who are viewing my site come from in real time, is there a program or a tool that allows me to view a world map and blink where the city or country where the request is coming from?

Comment: Seriously? Kind of like a Santa Tracker, but for your website?

Comment: Yea, something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has a realtime location view that'll let you drill down to country (and state/city in some areas).

[image]

If you want to do it yourself, you'll have to combine GeoIP and some web development.

Comment: Yea I know thanks! but I was hoping to do that exact same thing but as a personal project, I just need to know how to get the data from the request if it's possible